# Why Do Page Faults and Unrecoverable Errors Need to be Unmaskable?

Tags: c, operating-system, interrupt, page-fault

Looking for a quick clarification on why unrecoverable errors and page faults must be non-maskable interrupts? What happens when they aren't?

Comment: I was just looking for an answer to that exact question!

Comment: The hardware won't allow the interrupt to be masked, so "what happens when they aren't?" isn't really a meaningful question. What would happen if they could be masked? Well, the machine can't continue executing after an unrecoverable error, or when the memory it wants to read or write doesn't exist. So I guess it would have to explode or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Interrupts and exceptions are very different kinds of events.
An interrupt is external to a CPU event that happens and arrives in the processor asynchronously (moment of arrival does not depend on currently executing programs).
An exception is internal to a CPU event that happens as a side effect of instruction execution.

Consider processor as an overcomplex unstoppable automaton with a well-defined and strictly specified behavior. It continuously fetches, decodes, and executes instructions, one by one. When it executes each instruction, it applies the result to the state of the automaton (registers and memory) by its type. It moves without pauses and interrupts. You only can change the direction of this continuous instruction crunching using function calls and jumps.

Such an automaton-like model supported by well-defined and strictly specified instructions behavior makes it extremely predictable and convenient for programming for compilers and software engineers. When you look at the assembler listing, you can precisely say what the processor will do, when it will execute this program. However, under some specific circumstances, the execution of an instruction can fall out of this well-defined model. And in such cases CPU literally does not know what to do next and how to react. For example, the program tries to divide by zero. What reaction do you expect? What value does it need to place into the target register as a result of division? How can it report to the program that something goes wrong? Now imagine another case. The program makes a jump to some virtual address, but it has no physical address mapped. How should CPU proceed with its unstoppable fetch-decode-execute job? From where should it take the next instruction to execute? Which instruction should it execute? Or maybe it should hang in response? There are no ways out from such states.

An exception is a tool for the CPU to go out from such situations gracefully and restore its unstoppable movement. At the same time is a tool to report the encountered error to the operating system and ask it to help with its handling. If you can turn off exceptions, you can steal that tool from the CPU and put all of the above issues back on the table. CPU designers do not have good answers for them and do not what to see them. Due to this, they make exceptions unmaskable.